# ¿Cómo me muevo a arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha en una matriz en phyton?

Tags: python

estoy intentando crear un juego en python, en el cual debo crear una matriz con 0 y el número 1 representa el muñeco que se debe mover a las 4 cardinalidades, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenida a la comunidad, para que podamos ayudarte debes poner el código que tienes hasta ahora y indicar cual es el problema o duda que tienes.te recomiendo leer [ask] y dar un [tour] para enteder como funciona la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Debes aprender como preguntar en el sitio. De todos modos aqui te doy un ejemplito para que no te desanimes. Si no conoces sobre el modulo numpy puedes verlo [aqui](https://numpy.org/) y puedes instalarlo facilmente con pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

Esto que te muestro es con python3

```
import numpy as np

def move_up(board):
    for x in range(board.shape[0]):
        for y in range(board.shape[1]):
            if board[x, y] == 1:
                if x > 0:
                    board[x, y] = 0
                    board[x - 1, y] = 1
                    return
                else:
                    print("Movimiento invalido")

def move_down(board):
    for x in range(board.shape[0]):
        for y in range(board.shape[1]):
            if board[x, y] == 1:
                if x < board.shape[0] - 1:
                    board[x, y] = 0
                    board[x + 1, y] = 1
                    return
                else:
                    print("Movimiento invalido")

def move_left(board):
    for x in range(board.shape[0]):
        for y in range(board.shape[1]):
            if board[x, y] == 1:
                if y > 0:
                    board[x, y] = 0
                    board[x, y - 1] = 1
                    return
                else:
                    print("Movimiento invalido")

def move_right(board):
    for x in range(board.shape[0]):
        for y in range(board.shape[1]):
            if board[x, y] == 1:
                if y < board.shape[1] - 1:
                    board[x, y] = 0
                    board[x, y + 1] = 1
                    return
                else:
                    print("Movimiento invalido")

tablero = np.zeros((12, 12))
tablero[0, 0] = 1

print(tablero)
move_down(tablero)
print(tablero)
move_right(tablero)
print(tablero)
move_up(tablero)
print(tablero)
move_left(tablero)
```